Why LoRA is for fine-tuning but not for training too?
Wfinetuned = Wpretrained + ΔW, so we make ΔW = A @ B and |ΔW| >> |A| + |B|, we are happy. But, why don't we use the same method during training? So, Wtrained = Winitialized + ΔW,
and still |ΔW| >> |A| + |B|? And further we can make Wtrained = Winitialized + ΔW = C @ D + A @ B, |Winitialized + ΔW| >> |C| + |D| + |A| + |B|?

LoRA is a good choice for fine-tuning as it builds on pretrained weights ($W_{\text{pretrained}}$), using existing knowledge with low-rank updates ($\Delta W = A @ B$). If training from scratch, $W_{\text{initialized}}$ lacks pretrained structure, making low-rank updates ineffective. Full training requires unconstrained parameter exploration, which low-rank methods limit. Also, optimising all components ($C, D, A, B$) negates LoRA's efficiency. While promising for efficiency, low-rank training needs novel initialisation and stability strategies. Full-rank remains dominant for its flexibility.

The point of LoRA is to avoid the compute cost of training the full model. If you are already training the full model, there's no point using LoRA.
Furthermore, training the full rank matrices at the same time as LoRA is just composing linear transforms - ie going from y = x @ W to y = x @ W + x @ A @ B. Compositions of linear transforms are linear transforms. This means there exists some matrix D such that x @ D = x @ W + x @ A @ B. If you are training the full model, there's no advantage to adding the LoRA weights.
